# jquery : changing css attribute on content reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a slideshow run by cycle plugin and this apply a `position:absolute` of slides.
So I can to change this on page load with:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function()
    {        $('.views_slideshow_cycle_slide').css('position', 'relative', 'important');
        $('.views_slideshow_cycle_hidden').css('position', 'relative', 'important');
    });
```

But this is overridden when slides are loaded and class change from `views_slideshow_cycle_hidden` to `views_slideshow_cycle_slide`.

The Cycle / Views HTML produce:

```
<div class="views_slideshow_cycle_slide views_slideshow_slide views-row-1 views-row-odd" id="views_slideshow_cycle_div_Diapo_illustration-block_1_0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2; opacity: 1; display: block;">
  <div class="views-row views-row-0 views-row-first views-row-odd">

  <div class="views-field views-field-field-illus-lycee-fid">        <span class="field-content"><img src="//10.100.3.90:3000/sites/all/media/imagecache/MG_illustration_170x310/diapo_lycee/2017/22/abstract-h-c-1107-1142-8.jpg" alt="Lycée Marie Gasquet" title="Lycée Marie Gasquet" class="imagecache imagecache-MG_illustration_170x310 imagecache-default imagecache-MG_illustration_170x310_default"></span>  </div></div>
</div>
```

How can I do this on another jquery event different of `onload` ?
On document ready event, doesn't work better.
Thanks

Comment: Would you show us your HTML ?

Comment: Instead of modifying css on window's load, apply it on jQuery.(document).ready(); event. If it doesn't apply then either add some timeout or search for slider's callback event.

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz See edit please.